# Replace NULL values with values from join results

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a table where the value of a column can be NULL because those records have been created in the past. But now I would like to update those records. The tables are as follows:

```
TABLE 1
id | workflowId | workflowName | workflowVersion
1  | NULL       | 'name-1'     | 2
2  | NULL       | 'name-1'     | 3
3  | NULL       | 'name-1'     | 3
4  | NULL       | 'name-1'     | 3
5  | 2          | 'name-2'     | 1

TABLE2 
workflowId | workflowName | workflowVersion | target
1          | 'name-1'     | 2               | 'master'
2          | 'name-1'     | 3               | 'master'
3          | 'name-1'     | 4               | 'something'
4          | 'name-2'     | 1               | 'master'
```

It's a MySQL database.
In `TABLE1` I would like to update all the NULL values for `workflowId` with the actual workflow with the result of the query:

```
SELECT workflowId 
FROM table2 as t2, table1 as t1  
WHERE t2.workflowName = t1.workflowName 
and t2.workflowVersion = t1.workflowVersion 
and t2.target = 'master'
```

Another thing to notice is that `TABLE1` is much bigger than `TABLE2`, and executing that join for each record in `TABLE2` has a big cost. Ideally, I would like also to reduce the computational costs in parsing all the records in `TABLE1`, see if they have correspondences in `TABLE2` and to update them (as opposite of executing that join for each record in `TABLE2`).

 However, as long as I can find something that works for my case I would be happy.

Comment: You really should be using `JOIN`'s

Comment: FYI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd172122(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want an `update` with `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t2.workflowName = t1.workflowName and
          t2.workflowVersion = t1.workflowVersion 
    set t1.workflowId = t2.workflowId
    where t2.target = 'master' and t1.workflowId is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with cte as(
Select * from TABLE1 where workflowId is null
)
update cte 
set workflowId = table2.workflowId 
from cte inner join TABLE2 on cte.workflowName = table2.workflowName
```